# Export all records to excel from bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, export-to-excel, bootstrap-table

I Want to Export all records from my bootstrap table to excel sheet but at the moment only the records from current page are exporting.
So I am checking If in bootstrap itself any such option available or not.

I am using below bootstrap plugins

```
    <script  src="~/wwwroot/plugins/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
        
    <script src="~/wwwroot/plugins/bootstrap-table/extensions/toolbar/bootstrap-table-toolbar.js"></script>
      
     <script src="~/wwwroot/plugins/bootstrap-table/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js"></script>
            
   
<script src="~/wwwroot/plugins/bootstraptable/extensions/export/tableExport.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the [exportDataType](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/#exportdatatype) table option to `all`.
You can test it on this [example](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/export.html), just select `select all` on the selectbox, then export the data :-)

Comment: This solves nothing at all